# Красивый вывод var_dump

Tags: php

Что нужно изменить в `php.ini`, для того чтобы иметь человекочитаемый вывод, например, `var_dump` и `print_r`? Сейчас всё выводиться в один ряд, читать массивы с данными нереально.

Comment: Для этого надо написать собственный вывод )

Comment: А разве для этого не достаточно просто установить и включить xDebug?

Comment: можно настроить PHPStorm так, как показано в этом видео: [PHPStorm инструменты - Live Templates](https://youtu.be/_PIzZa0Owig)

Comment: >Сейчас всё выводиться в один ряд      `echo(nl2br(var_export( $forDump , true)))` Или просто нажать "Исходный код страницы" там где сделан дамп. Мне лично var_dump больше нравится чем xdebug - он не режет глаз.

Comment: в Laravel для этого есть команда dd

Comment: В вопросе о Lavarel врооде речи не идёт.

Comment: [Простая инструкция решения вопроса.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rii-kevMjlg)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
echo '<pre>'; 
var_dump($smth);
print_r($array); 
echo '</pre>';
```

**Обновление**

```
function vardump($var) {
  echo '<pre>';
  var_dump($var);
  echo '</pre>';
}
```

Использовать вместо `var_dump`. ))

Comment: @Get надоело постоянно обрамлять вардамп тегами. Я знаю, что можно сделать подобный вывод по умолчанию, но нагуглить не могу.

Comment: @sargss, ну написали уже, потсавьте xdebug просто.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: @Etki у меня и так установлен xdebug-2.2.0-5.3-vc9. В php.ini он включен

Comment: @sargss скриншот в студию, желательно самого html

Comment: @Get а в консоли будет работать подобная конструкция?

Answer (score 3):

```
function pr($var) {
    static $int=0;
    echo '<pre><b style="background: red;padding: 1px 5px;">'.$int.'</b> ';
    print_r($var);
    echo '</pre>';
    $int++;
}

function prv($var) {
    static $int=0;
    echo '<pre><b style="background: blue;padding: 1px 5px;">'.$int.'</b> ';
    var_dump($var);
    echo '</pre>';
    $int++;
}
```

Использование:

```
pr($var);

prv($var);
```

или

```
prv(json_decode('{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}'));
```

Примечание: $var может быть любой переменной, массивом или объектом.

Answer (score 3):

Разкомментируйте в `php.ini` строку:

```
zend_extension="%sprogdir%/modules/php/%phpdriver%/ext/php_xdebug.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo '<pre>' . print_r($arrayName, 1) . '</pre>';`

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]